# Como comparar dois valores em child's no Firebase

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, firebase

Eu tenho dois tipos de usuários: `Vendedores` e `Usuarios`. Os candidatos podem exibir seus dados se os IDs forem os mesmos (já funcionais). Os usuários devem ver os valores dos Vendedores se seu filho ("Cidade") tiver o mesmo valor.

Eu tentei:

```
//Vendedores
      "Vendedores": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid || (data.child(auth.uid).child('Cidade').val() === data.child($uid).child('Cidade').val())",
       ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
```

Mas é sempre `true`.

Comment: Poderia traduzir sua pergunta ?

Comment: Para ter acesso ao Vendedor, o usuário precisa ter na chave Cidade, a mesma "Cidade" / Varíavel, que o Vendedor possui.

Comment: Gostaria de saber como fazer isto. Uma vez que a regra que escrevi está sempre sendo true.

Comment: A sua pergunta está em inglês, você poderia traduzí-la para melhorar a experiência com os demais usuários.

Comment: Sou novo, não sabia que iria cair no fórum Brasileiro.

Comment: Fiz uns ajustes em sua pergunta!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu havia esquecido de referenciar corretamente o caminho. Pelo console de testes ficou funcional, a aplicação ainda está tendo o acesso negado.

```
 "Vendedores": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid || root.child('Usuarios').child(auth.uid).child('Cidade').val() == root.child('Vendedores').child($uid).child('Cidade').val()",
       ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }

}
```